# Copy/Paste option from TextView to EditText in android

Tags: android, clipboardmanager

In my android app I want to give simple copy paste option.
User can copy text from text view by long clicking on it and I am successfully complete it, But not getting how can paste it to a edit text.
I am trying long press on a edit text but paste option is not available.

I know I can get content from ClipBoardManager by below code -

```
ClipboardManager clipMan = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(v.getContext().CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
 myEdtTxt.setText(clipMan.getText());
```

but not getting how to get paste option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't this already available with the `Context Action Bar` ?

Comment: Why don't you use a string to store the text from the TextView and add it to the EditText?

Comment: I think you are not getting my question.i  want to give paste option to user.when user long press on edit text there should an option for paste content from clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `android:cursorVisible="true"` in your `EditText`'s layout `xml`

Comment: try but still not giving option for paste in edit  text

Comment: try giving `android:textIsSelectable = "true"` for `TextView` and `android:cursorVisible="true"` for `EditText`

Comment: I can copy text but how to give paste option when user long press on edit text.

Comment: Does your theme Theme contains ActionBar ?

Comment: No, I am using FragmentActivity

Comment: I'm asking about "Theme". You may have FragmentActivity but you can set theme to ActionBar. Try it add a new theme in styles, give it to your activity in manifest and try

Comment: My Current theme is  - Theme.AppCompat.Light

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83851/discussion-between-logic-and-guess).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, it may be simpler to use Android's in built `Context Action Bar`. This will allow you to copy/paste text reliably and with the least amount of effort.

If you want to `copy` text from a `TextView`, not an `EditText`, you will first need to make it selectable. For that you can either add the following `xml` attribute:

```
android:textIsSelectable = "true"
```

Or add the following programmatically:

```
textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

Comment: as I mention in my question I am able to copy text,but don't know how to give paste option to user in edit text.

Comment: Just do a long press on any `EditText` field, and by default a `Contextual Action Menu` will appear and allow the paste option. Here's a screenshot I took a second ago: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BygzWY4QsrwESmswZXd6S3dyQ2c/view?usp=sharing